# Failed to build body from content in activeMQ - Spring generic message used

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic, spring-jms, jmstemplate

I send a `org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage` to a queue in ActiveMQ by `org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate`. in ActiveMQ, I see this message :

```
Cannot display ObjectMessage body. Reason: Failed to build body from content. 
    Serializable class not available to broker. 
    Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage
```

and so I can't read that message in a client.
I set trustAllPackages to true in my activeMQConnectionFactory and problem doesn't solve. How to solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

The `JmsTemplate` will serialize the entire `GenericMessage` as a java object, so `spring-messaging` is needed on the class path of the receiving system as well.

> class not available to broker.

It looks like you might be trying to view the message in the admin UI, which doesn't understand spring-messaging classes.

If you want to map the GenericMessage to a JMS Message instead, use the `JmsMessagingTemplate` instead (one of the `send()` methods); the broker might be able to display such a message (depending on the payload type).

Answer (score 0):

Simply put:

Add the required jar or class files or the serialised messages in the lib folder of activemq and restart activemq.

It worked for me